# In Android Cells are not staggered in using RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android

Cells are not staggered in using RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager in Android

---

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="226dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center">

        <!-- android:src="@drawable/three"-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="$100"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/country_photo"
           android:layout_marginTop="2sp"

            android:background="#ffffff"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="@string/country_name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/price"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Descripition"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="Descripition"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/country_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/country_photo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
            android:src="@drawable/three"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: Can you please update your post to include your code, xml layout, and a screenshot? Other we will have no idea where the problem is.

Comment: I used  cardview and recycle view with staggred..but cells are like grid,they are not changing

Comment: please mention the part of code where you are setting Layout Manager for RecyclerView

Comment: Please post your XML file. I have an idea what the problem is, but without seeing it, it's impossible for anyone to give you a correct answer.

Comment: I added my Xml file

Comment: @Abserve Tech, if my answer worked for you, could you please accept it so the question can be closed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `CardView`'s `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content`, otherwise every `CardView` will have a fixed height of `300dp`, meaning they will all be the same height.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center">

    <!-- android:src="@drawable/three"-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="$100"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country_photo"
       android:layout_marginTop="2sp"

        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="@string/country_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/price"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Descripition"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="Descripition"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/country_photo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
        android:src="@drawable/three"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```